# Raspberry Pi doesn´t find "flask_cors" module in autorun boot

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, boot, autostart, autorun

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6qZT.png)

The module flask_cors can not be found in the autorun

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v55oc.png)

if I run the app manually it´s working fine

Answer (score 0):

When you say "cannot be found in autorun", do you mean that occurs when it starts on boot from rc.local?

I think that your problem might be that you have the flask_cors module installed as the pi user and not su.

Try "sudo pip3 install flask-cors".

A tip - try running your app as sudo and you'll see any errors that occur when running the app as su. If it won't run like that but will as the pi user then it's not going to run started in rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

The Tip to install the cores in sudo and to run the app as sudo was very good.
The app is running but if I try to interact with the app it returns
"Internal Server Error"
"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Thanks for the fast and helpful answer